# Jetpack Compose - no recomposition, why?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, state

im very confused now, because i thought that if a state changes or a composable is altered, like the text of a button, or the size, it would initiate a recomposition of that composable.

In my example there is a suspendfunction **timerForCompose()** which prints after a certain delay the message: "Timer ended". If the coroutine did stop it should print "Timer cancelled". The suspendfunction is called in the composableFunction **Timer()**, and will be executed in the lambda of the LaunchedEffect-Composable.

My MainComposablefunction is called **TimerScreen1** and consits of a Button. On AppStart or Recomposition the size of the button changes and **Timer()** receives the initial delay time, provided by the state object **timerDuration.**

Here is the code:

**The supend-function:**

```
suspend fun timerForCompose(time: Long, onTimerEnd: () -> Unit){
delay(timeMillis = time)
onTimerEnd()
}
```

**Timer Composable Function**

```
@Composable
fun Timer(timerDuration: Long) {

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit){

    try {
        timerForCompose(timerDuration){
            println("Timer ended successfully")
        }
    }
    catch (ex: Exception){
        println("Timer canceled")
    }}  }
```

**TimerScreen1 function:**

```
@Composable
```

fun TimerScreen1() {

```
var dpForButton = remember {
    mutableStateOf(200.dp)
}

var timerDuration = remember {
    mutableLongStateOf(4000L)
}

    Button(onClick = { dpForButton.value = 400.dp }, modifier = Modifier.size(dpForButton.value)) {
        Text(timerDuration.value.toString())
        Timer(timerDuration = timerDuration.value + 2000L)

    } }
```

The problem: I dont understand why the ButtonComposable is not recomposing every time i click on the button. For me it would be logical that if i click, the whole Button gets recomposed and with that Timer()-function would be called again. But this does not happen.
It only recomposes if i rotate the screen. You might be wondering why timerDuration has a state. Its because the initial Code was like here:

```html
https://betterprogramming.pub/jetpack-compose-side-effects-launchedeffect-with-example-99c2f51ff463
```

I just tried to break it down to that button, cause i expected a recomposition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/8fb9fb298ff2adbfdee29f342e9af1acc950d6e0:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/SnapshotState.kt;l=83) of `MutableState` says:

> When the `value` property is written to and changed, a recomposition of any subscribed `RecomposeScope`s will be scheduled. If `value` is written to with the same value, no recompositions will be scheduled.

So this is the problem - you always set the same value to `dpForButton`, so recomposition is not scheduled.

---

Another problem is that you are calling `timerForCompose` inside of `LaunchedEffect` with `key = Unit`, which means that the code inside of that effect will only run the first time it enters composition. If you want to run it every time it recomposes, you should use [`SideEffect`](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/8fb9fb298ff2adbfdee29f342e9af1acc950d6e0:compose/runtime/runtime/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/Effects.kt;l=47).

Comment: Im sorry but i dont understand the anwser provided by you. If i use remember by i need a var and if i say onClick dpForButton = 400.dp the value changes, or not?

Comment: The first time you click yes, it changes from the default value of 200dp to 400dp and that should trigger the recomposition. But when you click for the second time, the value is already 400dp, so the second sentence from docs applies and recomposition wont be triggered. And you asked "I dont understand why the ButtonComposable is not recomposing **every time** i click on the button."

Comment: ok my question was not exact enough. The problem is that even if i click for the first time, i dont receive the println() from the LaunchedEffect "Timer canceled" or "Timer ended". Cause what i expect is, that if the button recomposes, then it should call the function Timer(). But it doesnt. It gets only called if i rotate the device, or for the first time i open the application.

Comment: I see, there is another problem in your code, updated the answer.

Comment: Ok somehow i thought that if a Composable recomposes, every function inside the lambda would also get recalled again. Seems that its not the case. In the docs: "When Compose recomposes based on new inputs, it only calls the functions or lambdas that might have changed, and skips the rest." Thats why Timer() get not called again, because timerduration does not change on click?!